# Matching multiple columns in a nested query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make a nested query, where I return values from multiple columns and match those with values from another column. Something similar to the code below (this is for work so I can't put the exact code here)

```
select *
from store1
where (orderNum, customer, total) not in (
select orderNum, customer, total from store2)
```

When I try to run the code, I get the error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Is there a way to do this is SQL Server. I know using a join is an option but I'd prefer to avoid that at this time. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is your rationale for trying to avoid a join? Its a normal SQL tool... `NOT EXISTS` is probably what you want.

Comment: At this point I don't understand joins enough to implement it into the solution. In particular multiple joins, which this query already utilizes. For the sake of development deadline I was looking for another solution but I am definitely open to update the query to be cleaner as I come to understand SQL more.

Comment: Side point: `IN` and `NOT IN`, as well as `EXISTS`, are all types of joins, specifically semi-joins

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't support table constructors like that, but there are lots of other ways to do it. My preferred approach is `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.store1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
     SELECT 1 FROM dbo.store2
     WHERE store1.orderNum = store2.orderNum
       AND store1.customer = store2.customer
       AND store1.total = store2.total
  );
```

For other approaches, see:

- [Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: That works! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

"count" returns a single value, works fast. Easy to understand.

```
select *
from store1
where 
(select count(*) from store2 where store2.orderNum=store1.orderNum and store2.customer=store1.customer and store2.total=store1.total)=0
```